# I want solution lock row with Sequelize v5 MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, transactions, sequelize.js

I try this like this

```
try {
    let t;
    t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
    let event1 = await db.EventModel.findOne(
      {
        where: { id: 1 }
      },
      {
        transaction: t
      }
    );
    let event2 = await db.EventModel.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });
    await event2.update({ event_name: "test2" });
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await event1.update({ event_name: "test1" }, { transaction: t });
      await t.commit();
      console.log("");
    }, 10000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("", error);
  }
```

this is log data

```
result before update event2 {
  id: 1,
  event_name: 'make event name',
  createdAt: 2020-01-23T08:25:12.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-01-26T18:02:33.000Z
}
result after update event2 {
  id: 1,
  event_name: 'test2',
  createdAt: 2020-01-23T08:25:12.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-01-26T18:03:59.000Z
}
result after update event1 {
  id: 1,
  event_name: 'test1'
  createdAt: 2020-01-23T08:25:12.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-01-26T18:04:09.000Z
}
```

The row event.id = 1 is not locked.

So I try

```
try {
    let t;
    t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
    let event1 = await db.EventModel.findOne({
      where: { id: 1 },
      transaction: t,
      lock: {
        level: t.LOCK.NO_KEY_UPDATE
      }
    });
    let event2 = await db.EventModel.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });
    await event2.update({ event_name: "test2" });
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await event1.update({ event_name: "test1" }, { transaction: t });
      await t.commit();
      console.log("");
    }, 10000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("", error);
  }
```

wait 50 seconds then my app log like this

```
 DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at Query.formatError (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:244:16)
    at Execute.handler [as onResult] (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:51:23)
    at Execute.execute (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:30:14)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:417:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:219:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:332:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:307:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:241:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:185:23)
From previous event:
    at Query.run (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:39:12)
    at /Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:645:29
From previous event:
    at /Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:645:12
From previous event:
    at /Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:641:10
    at /Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:70:21
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at retryAsPromised (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:60:10)
    at /Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:631:30
From previous event:
    at Sequelize.query (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:580:23)
    at QueryInterface.update (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:1012:27)
    at /Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:3985:52
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:444:21)
From previous event:
    at EventModel.save (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:3962:8)
    at EventModel.update (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:4176:17)
    at module.exports (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/src/databaseLoader/index.js:19:18)
    at async /Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/server.js:78:5 {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
      at Packet.asError (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
      at Execute.execute (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:417:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:219:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:332:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:307:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:241:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:185:23) {
    code: 'ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT',
    errno: 1205,
    sqlState: 'HY000',
    sqlMessage: 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction',
    sql: 'UPDATE `events` SET `event_name`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?',
    parameters: [ 'test2', '2020-01-26 17:50:36', 1 ]
  },
  original: Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
      at Packet.asError (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
      at Execute.execute (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:417:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/akkarapongkhamtanet/Documents/MyWorks/joindi/back-end/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:219:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:332:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:307:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:241:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:185:23) {
    code: 'ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT',
    errno: 1205,
    sqlState: 'HY000',
    sqlMessage: 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction',
    sql: 'UPDATE `events` SET `event_name`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?',
    parameters: [ 'test2', '2020-01-26 17:50:36', 1 ]
  },
  sql: 'UPDATE `events` SET `event_name`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?',
  parameters: [ 'test2', '2020-01-26 17:50:36', 1 ]
}
```

**I want lock row when opening a transaction** .
I tried to read the document(https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/transaction.js~Transaction.html#static-get-LOCK) and lock row can't use the lock.
help me, please
I read document